# completely stop skype on linux

Tags: linux, skype, skype-for-linux

So it looks like the latest version of Skype for Linux (I'm using 8.11.0.4) has a helpful "misfeature".  If you close the Skype window, the ui disappears, but Skype does not quit -- there are at least four "skypeforlinux" processes still running.

More imporantly, they keep chewing up network resources.  This really hurt me recently when I was overseas and on a connection that as both slow and metered.

Any ideas how to tell Skype "stop means stop"?  (I can go find the processes and kill them myself, which satisfies my techno-bloodlust, but I'd really just like to have the program behave nicely.

Comment: So does it works for you any of the solution reported below?

Comment: Thanks for the reminder.  Correct answer marked. (uncheck "on close keep skype running")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### From the options.

Go on `Tools--> Settings-->` un-check the option `On Close keep skype running`.

#### From the `skypeforlinux` window

Go on `Files-> Quit`, or press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>- <kbd>Q</kbd>, (at least this key combination works under kde).

#### From the icon on the bar

With mouse <kbd>Right-Click</kbd>, quit skype

#### From the command-line

```
kill -TERM skypeforlinux
```

You may wait, check for `pgrep skypeforlinux`, then if needed the holy `kill -9 skypeforlinux`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can send a TERM signal (instead of KILL). If the application is well programmed, it will stop gracefully.

Comment: “If the application is well programmed...”. This is a very optimistic outlook for a Microsoft product running on Linux. Especially given the mess they’ve made of Skype lately.

Comment: @Darren [e.g.](https://superuser.com/q/1289770/257269)