# Blank White Screen On Skype after a successful login

Tags: linux, ubuntu, skype, skype-for-linux

I'm running `skypeforlinux` under  Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS (*“**L**ong **T**erm **S**upport”*).
After the login procedure the skype window becomes white, allowing me to open each of the commands-menu, but practically allowing me only to minimize the window itself or to close the program.

I've tried to update `skypeforlinux`, then to upgrade all the system with no success.
I've tried to *reinstall* the package with no success again 
(`sudo apt-get remove skypeforlinux` then `sudo apt-get install skypeforlinux`, eventually even using the `--purge` option for the removing command).
Even if not usually needed under Linux, neither expressly request by the update procedure, I even reboot the system. Same situation.

From `apt-cache policy skypeforlinux` I obtain

```
skypeforlinux:
  Installed: 8.13.0.2
  Candidate: 8.13.0.2
  Version table:
 *** 8.13.0.2 0
        500 https://repo.skype.com/deb/ stable/main amd64 Packages
     8.11.0.4 0
        500 https://repo.skype.com/deb/ stable/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     8.10.0.4 0
        500 https://repo.skype.com/deb/ stable/main amd64 Packages
     8.9.0.1 0
        500 https://repo.skype.com/deb/ stable/main amd64 Packages
     5.5.0.1 0
        500 https://repo.skype.com/deb/ stable/main amd64 Packages
```

**The issue started after an update** (`sudo apt-get upgrade`), but I didn't notice it in the beginning because `skype` starts *minimized* and it didn't throw out errors. Moreover I cannot be sure if it happens after a `skypeforlinux` update or after some other library update, but I think after the update of the skype package.

**Update:**
Same problem with the following versions `8.14.0.10`, `8.15.0.4`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Update

With the last version (`8.16.0.4`) but after around 3 weeks, the update will solve the problem.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

### *Quick & dirty* solution

This seems to be a recurring bug (see below).

A *quick & dirty* working solution is to to install a previous working version
(in this case the `8.11.0.4 0`).

```
sudo apt-get install skypeforlinux=8.11.0.4
```

---

Unfortunately this seems to be a recurrent behaviour (or bug) that we find not only on the specific Ubuntu version <sup>[[1](https://askubuntu.com/q/972539/196535),[2](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/skype/forum/skype_linux-skype_startms-skype_signms/blank-white-screen-on-skype/8fc61b0d-8ed7-4dbd-8aec-471995df4d22?auth=1)]</sup>, or on the current one (`8.13.0.2`): it is reported such a issue starting from the  `8.9.0.1` <sup>[[3](https://paste.ubuntu.com/25895182/)]</sup>, bug fixed at that time installing the Preview version 8.10.76.2 as you can find as the only working suggestion in the official microsoft forum for skype.
<sub>**Notes:** For that version there was not a previous working one other than the 5.5.0.1 I think already disabled by MicroSoft.</sub>
<sub>Moreover it may result useful to read [this answer to the question "How to install skype in Ubuntu 16.04"](https://askubuntu.com/a/775092/196535) and its links.</sub>

---

Now the output of `apt-cache policy skypeforlinux` should give something similar to

```
skypeforlinux:
  Installed: 8.11.0.4 
  Candidate: 8.13.0.2
  Version table:
     8.13.0.2 0
        500 https://repo.skype.com/deb/ stable/main amd64 Packages
 *** 8.11.0.4 0
        500 https://repo.skype.com/deb/ stable/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     8.10.0.4 0
        500 https://repo.skype.com/deb/ stable/main amd64 Packages
     8.9.0.1 0
        500 https://repo.skype.com/deb/ stable/main amd64 Packages
     5.5.0.1 0
        500 https://repo.skype.com/deb/ stable/main amd64 Packages
```

---

**Update:** The new versions (8.14.0.10, 8.15.0.4) continue to spring but the problem persist.
This solution continue to be the only working I found.